# I get this NullPointerException while running the program

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

the application stops working suddenly because of the NullPointerException but still can't fix it.

and that's what appears to me ...(https://i.stack.imgur.com/saMPw.png)

i tried the try and catch method but couldn't fix it

Comment: Make sure `mQuestionsList` is not `null`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `!!` operator on `mQuestionsList`, which throws a `NullPointerException`, use the Elvis operator `?:` like so:

```kotlin
val question: Question = mQuestionsList?[mCurrentPosition - 1] ?: defaultQuestion
```

I would recommend avoiding the `!!` operator in most cases, instead you can use other null safety operators such as `?.` and `?:`.

Comment: I tried it but got an error ....but i get your point

Answer (score 0):

Seems like mQuestionsList is null. you can verify that by logging or adding a debug point on line 60 and running in debug mode.

You can avoid this by adding a null check and handling the logic accordingly.

Note that the !! operator asserts that the object is NOT null and its usage is NOT recommended.

You can refer to this for better understanding of usage of null check in kotlin:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions